# Is there any algorithm which can solve this number group sequence?

Tags: algorithm, numbers, set

I hava a problem which is described below. Do you have any good solution or this problem is just another form of any "classics" or "have been solved" problem?

The problem is :

There are some group of numbers,e.g.

A(1 8 9)

B(1 4 5)

C(2 4 6)

D(3 4 7)

E(2 10 11)

F(3 12 13)

There are "A-F" six group. we have numbers "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13".
Now find the minimum amount of number set which satisfies each group must have a number in this set at least. For examlpe, we can find the set "1 4 2 13 12" that A has "1",B has "1,4",C has "2,4",D has "4" ,E has "2",F has "12,13" .

But set "1 2 4" is not that we find ,F does not has any number in the set.

The best set is "1,2,3",every gruop has a number in the set,and the size of the set is optimal. It has only three numbers. THIS is What we want. If there are many best sets,finding any one is OK. Thanks.

Comment: What is the size of your universe? Your example uses 13 numbers, do you expect to get a lot more than that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is equivalent to the [set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem). In this case, each of your sets A, B, ..., F are the elements of the set cover problem, and each of the numbers 1, 2, ..., 13 are the sets. For example, in this mapping 1 becomes {A, B}, and 11 becomes the set {E}.

Set cover is NP-hard. The integer linear programming formulation on the linked Wikipedia page is probably as good as you'll get for exact solutions; the greedy algorithm there is a decent approximation for large problems.

Comment: I find it amusing that we each found reductions from different NP-hard problems within about 20 seconds of each other. :-)

Comment: @templatetypedef I was just about to post essentially the same thing on your answer. :)

Comment: I personally think set cover is a better fit (more intuitive reduction) than vertex cover, so I'm upvoting this answer. ;)

Answer (score 4):

This problem is NP-hard via a reduction from the [NP-hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard) [vertex cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover_problem) (given a graph, can you find a set of k nodes such that every vertex in the graph is adjacent to some chosen node?)

The reduction is as follows.  Number all of the nodes in the graph 1, 2, 3, ..., n in any order that you'd like.  Then, for each edge in the graph, construct the set containing just two numbers - the edge's endpoints.  If there is a k-node vertex cover in the original graph, then there is a set of k numbers you can pick (namely, the nodes in the vertex cover) such that you have one number chosen from each set.  This can be computed in polynomial-time.

To see why the reduction works, note that if there is a set of size k you can pick such that each set in the construction has at least one element picked, then the vertices corresponding to those numbers form a k-element vertex cover in the original graph.

This reduction can be done in polynomial-time, so we have a polynomial-time reduction from the NP-hard vertex-cover problem to your problem.  Thus this problem is NP-hard.  So, unless [P = NP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem), there is no polynomial-time algorithm for this problem.

Hope this helps!